# Populate [leaflet] Markers with CMS (eg Wordpress, Drupal etc)

Tags: leaflet

I have to start by stating that leaflet.js is plain awesomeness! Started yesterday and have decent results already.

Is it possible to populate map markers with a CMS? So the client can login to their websites backend (probably a new one in addition to their existing one) and add, change and remove markers (including position, icon, layer and popup content)...

If yes, where would I start educating myself about that?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Rick, welcome to SO :)
Stack overflow works best when you actually try something, show us the code of the attempt, so then we can comment on it. Did you try something so far?

Comment: Hey Wurm,
I understand. In this case I wanted to make sure to start with something that will work in the end. I could show you my map with a few basic markers. If I found something with google I would have tried. Just didn't want to try anything completele out of the blue. 

Was hoping someone would say something like "yes, wordpress will work" or "no, theres another cms that works great with leaflet. Google for xyz..." or even "no, you have to write your own leaflet-cms"

Anyway. Will experiment and come back with some code...